# SupportMapFragment set google maps Zoom level

Tags: android, zooming, supportmapfragment

how can i set the zoom level of a `SupportMapFragment` ?
I tried some answers I found in similar questions, like  this one answered buy a guy named Rob who proposed:

```
LatLng currentLocation = mService.getCurrentLocation();
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(currentLocation)    // Sets the center of the map to the current location of the user
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

But this solution didn't work. So, how can I set the Zoom level knowing that I use a `SupportMapFragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your current location is not null then try this code it will work

```
LatLng currentLocation = mService.getCurrentLocation();
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation , 16);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(""));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation ));
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Marker currentMarker;

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new
                     LatLng(Double.
                     parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lon))).title(title);
                     marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_schoolbus));
                     currentMarker =  map.addMarker(marker);
                     currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
                     currentMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_schoolbus));
                     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lon)), 15));
```